# SQL many-to-many JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, many-to-many

i am having difficulties joining two tables.

I have the tables

```
Customer_table
 ---------------------------------------
| CustomerId(PK) | Firstname | Lastname |
 ---------------------------------------

CustomerInterest_table
 ----------------------------------------
| CustomerId(PK,FK) | InterestId(PK,FK)  |
 ----------------------------------------

Interest_table
 -------------------------------
| InterestId(PK) | InterestInfo |
 -------------------------------
```

What i want to do is to select every customer, and join the interests with the FK reference on the table.

Ultimately i want to fetch a result containing the customers fetched from the customer table, and the customer interests fetched from the CustomerInterest_table.

Id like to build objects like this

```
{
customerId : 'Id12345,
firstname : 'John', 
lastname : 'Doe', 
interests : [{interestId : 1, interestInfo : 'Apples'}]
}
```

How would i go about fetching and joining the tables ?
Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Database design ([First Normal Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form)) suppose that column should be simple type, in you case it mean no-array. Instead you can fetch desired from multiple selected rows:

```
SELECT customerId, firstname, lastname, interestId, InterestInfo 
    FROM Customer_table c
    INNER JOIN CustomerInterest_table tc
        ON c.customerId = tc.customerId
    INNER JOIN Interest_table i 
        ON tc.InterestId = i.InterestId
ORDER BY customerId
```

Last `ORDER BY` allows you force order of rows so interests of the same customer will follow one by one.

Alternatively if customer MAY not have interests you can leverage `LEFT JOIN` (then two columns interestId, InterestInfo will be NULL)

```
SELECT customerId, firstname, lastname, interestId, InterestInfo 
    FROM Customer_table c
    LEFT OUTER JOIN CustomerInterest_table tc
        ON c.customerId = tc.customerId
    INNER JOIN Interest_table i 
        ON tc.InterestId = i.InterestId
ORDER BY customerId
```

**UPDATE**

Alternatively (if you really want everything in single column for any cost) you can cast result to XML datatype, Then Last column will compose complex XML:

```
SELECT customerId, firstname, lastname
 , [Name]
 , (STUFF((SELECT CAST(', ' + interestId AS VARCHAR(MAX) + ':' + InterestInfo) 
     FROM Interest_table i
     WHERE tc.InterestId = i.InterestId
     FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 2, '')) AS interests 
FROM Customer_table c
    INNER JOIN CustomerInterest_table tc
        ON c.customerId = tc.customerId
```

(p.s. sorry syntax is not checked for correctness)

Comment: You beat me to it, except the Order By clause. Didnt think of that :)

Comment: Thanks! Great approach, and +1 for the handling of null interests!
Works like a charm,